# Ubuntu - trying to install Python Couchbase lib - "libcouchbase/couchbase.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, linux, couchbase

All,

I'm trying to install the Python Couchbase lib in my Linux server, but it's failing with "libcouchbase/couchbase.h: No such file or directory".  I also cannot find which package contains the couchbase.h file.  How can I fix this?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-167:~$ sudo easy_install couchbase
Searching for couchbase
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/couchbase/
Best match: couchbase 1.2.4
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/couchbase/couchbase-1.2.4.tar.gz#md5=4a51bf3ac1fa26bcb9433d53ac4ba34b
Processing couchbase-1.2.4.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-ZF8OtY/couchbase-1.2.4/setup.cfg
Running couchbase-1.2.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-ZF8OtY/couchbase-1.2.4/egg-dist-tmp-Az4Noq
In file included from src/exceptions.c:17:0:
src/pycbc.h:25:36: fatal error: libcouchbase/couchbase.h: No such file or directory
 #include 
                                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-167:~$ apt-file search couchbase.h
python-celery-doc: /usr/share/doc/python-celery-doc/html/_modules/celery/backends/couchbase.html
python-celery-doc: /usr/share/doc/python-celery-doc/html/internals/reference/celery.backends.couchbase.html
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this: http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-c-2.3/#downloading-the-couchbase-client-library

So if you have Ubuntu 12.04:

1. `sudo wget -O/etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchbase.list http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase-ubuntu1204.list`
2. `wget -O- http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase.key | sudo apt-key add -`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install libcouchbase2-libevent libcouchbase-dev`

Comment: This worked for me on my ubuntu14.04 instance.  All I had to do was change line #1 to `sudo wget -O/etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchbase.list http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase-ubuntu1404.list`

Comment: i am getting this error he following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcouchbase-dev : Depends: libcouchbase2-core (= 2.8.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
 libcouchbase2-libev : Depends: libcouchbase2-core (= 2.8.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y  libcouchbase-dev  libcouchbase2-libev' returned a non-zero code: 100

Answer (score 4):

Updated solution for Ubuntu 18.04

1. echo "deb http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu bionic bionic/main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchbase.list
2. wget -O- http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase.key | sudo apt-key add -
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install libcouchbase2-libevent libcouchbase-dev

Comment: i don't know, this broke my pip3

Answer (score 1):

They actually wrote a perl script to make the installation easier and safer, so you can:

1. `wget http://packages.couchbase.com/clients/c/couchbase-csdk-setup`
2. `sudo perl couchbase-csdk-setup`

As explained [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/c-2.4/download-install.html#c-download-install).

Comment: The script runs great, but keep running into unable to locate package errors. Are couchbase libs not yet available for Xenial?

Answer (score 0):

My Dockerfile (Debian 10)

```
# couchbase 2.x requires C libs
USER root
RUN wget -O - http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase.key | apt-key add -
# Adding Ubuntu 18.04 repo to apt/sources.list of 18.10 or 19.04
RUN echo "deb http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu bionic bionic/main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchbase.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libcouchbase-dev libcouchbase2-bin build-essential
USER ${USER}

# -- Install dependencies: --deploy aborts if the python version
# or Pipfile.lock dependencies are incorrect 
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock ./
RUN pipenv install --ignore-pipfile --deploy --system
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to build my repo having this dependencies. Hope this works for you as well.

```html
FROM ruby:2.3.0
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY . /myapp/
RUN apt-get update -y
#RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y lsb-release

RUN wget http://packages.couchbase.com/releases/couchbase-release/couchbase-release-1.0-6-amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i couchbase-release-1.0-6-amd64.deb
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install libcouchbase-dev libcouchbase2-bin build-essential -y
```